# Do I need to display the apache licence in my app when using phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, licensing, cordova

The apache 2.0 licence says the licence should be included in derivitive works, but I couldn't see if that was applicable to compiled code.

I've noticed a lack of EULA or Licence attribution in mobile apps in general, should apps need an information page in my app that lists the platforms/plugins used and the licence terms of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the official [FAQ](http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html#WhatDoesItMEAN):

> [The Apache 2.0 license] forbids you to:
>
> redistribute any piece of Apache-originated software without proper
>   attribution;

and

> [The Apache 2.0 license] requires you to:
>
> include a copy of the license in any redistribution you may make that
>   includes Apache software;

In practice, including a 'license.txt' document noting that the software was developed with code licensed under Apache, as well as a copy of the Apache license itself, seems to suffice based on what I've seen others do, but whether those developers have consulted with an attorney prior to doing so I cannot say.

Apps on the Google Play store actually have a provision for including a license that users may view before downloading the app, but in practice, it seems that most developers ignore that provision, perhaps relying on their status as small-fry to go unnoticed.

Note, also, that I'm am not an attorney, and am most definitely not **your** attorney. If there's money involved, it's a good idea to consult with an attorney rather than someone on SO.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will wait on a few more replies before considering which one is the 'perfect' answer. But it's looking likely that I'll have to consider an 'information'/'about' page that lists 3rd party components and links to licences.

Comment: Just confirming -- including a license.txt in a binary that no one will see seems to suffice? My app is not open-source.

Comment: @VaddadiKartick You must have missed the part where I indicated that I'm not an attorney, so here it is again: I am not an attorney. So what could you possibly be confirming with me?

Comment: I'm confirming that I correctly understood your opinion that including a license.txt in the binary that no one will see is enough to comply with the license. I'm building an iOS app, so the part you said about Google Play doesn't apply. You already said many times that you're not an attorney, so there's no need to repeat that any more.